# print elements's list of an instance of class in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Given the code below, i only have one issue. I try to print the elements's list (list_fils) of instances of class "Noeud" but it gives me this (example for Node 0):

```
Children of Node  0  are:  [<__main__.Noeud object at 0x7f7d1a5009b0>, <__main__.Noeud object at 0x7f7d1a500b38>]
```

what can i do to print the elements of that list ? Here's my program:

```
class Noeud:
    def __init__(self,val):
        self.val=val
        self.list_fils=[] #list containing children of the instance


 # K is number of levels of our binary tree
 #if we have k=2 levels, we need to iterate until Node with index (2^0)-1=0
 #if we have k=3 levels, we need to iterate until Node with index (2^0 + 2^1)-1 = 2
 #if we have k=4 levels, we need to iterate until Node with index (2^0 + 2^1 + 2^2)-1=6
 #if we have k levels, we need to iterate until Node with index (2^0+ 2^1 +.....+2^(k-2))
 def stop_index_for_level(K):
      Sum=0
      for x in range(K-1):
          Sum+=2**x
      return Sum-1

  #for each node(i) in l we add children of this node(i) to the list_fils attribute
  def Exo3(K,l):
      Debut=1
      for i in range(stop_index_for_level(K)+1):
          Fin=Debut+2
          l[i].list_fils.extend(l[Debut:Fin])
          Debut=Fin

  #our binary tree example (Note: each level must be completed)
                #0
              #/  \
             #1   2
            #/\  /\
           #3 4 5 6
  List_Nodes=[Noeud(i) for i in range(7)] #[0,1,2,3,4,5,6]
  Exo3(3,List_Nodes)

  for x in range(len(List_Nodes)):
      print("Children of Node ",List_Nodes[x].val," are: ",List_Nodes[x].list_fils)
```

Comment: What do you expect to be printed?

Comment: You *are* printing them.

Comment: Could you double check your indentation?  It looks like you have a lot of code that is inside your class but outside of the methods (are those even supposed to be methods?)

Comment: take a look at `__str__` and `__repr__` magic method for your Node class.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh my bad i didn't notice. they're now properly indented

Comment: @hd1 i want to print a list of numbers, where these numbers represent children nodes of an instance

Comment: @hamzasaber https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__